# How to handle Python files with Apache

Tags: python, apache, cgi

So I want to get into React Native development and have decided Python to be my backend, but for some reason I cannot configure the Apache correctly. The only way to successfully get the result from the request is to include path to `python.exe` at the start of the document like so:

```
!C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects\AppName\venv\Scripts\python.exe
```

But the problem is that the file is than executed by the Python console, and if I want to access it via mobile phone I get this error:

> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

So my question is:

Is there any way in which I can configure Apache to execute a file, without the requirement of the py console, so the request might be handled by devices, which doesn't have a Python console installed?

Comment: I don't understand you problem - Apache runs on server and if it runs python code then it runs it on server, not on user device. Maybe you doesn't run it with Apache. Do you have installed module `mod_cgi` or `mod_fcgi` or `mod_python` in Apache? Or maybe use more popular method and use any web framework like Flask/Django instead of using Apache.

Comment: Well my problem is whenever I send request to get the file, which is written in python, this error is shown.

"The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script. " 

I cannot make apache to execute the file properly, I have enabled mod_cgi.so. Also created specific <Directory/> in httpd.conf which is responsible only for python files... Will probably try Django or Flask, but I just was curious if apache can execute python files.

Comment: Apache should write some information in log files and you should find more information in logs - maybe there will be some error message from Python which could help to recognize problem.

Comment: BTW: as I know as standard it runs files only in subfolder `cgi-bin/` so first you can try t put code in this folder. On Linux script would need shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python` in first line and it should be executable - `chmod a+x script.py`

Comment: [cgi:error] [pid 11040:tid 1892] (9)Bad file descriptor: [client 192.168.1.3:56202] AH01222: don't know how to spawn child process: C:/Users/Name/PycharmProjects/AppName/HelloWorld.py

Already checked the log, that is the error.
For the second answer, the point is that if i use shebang with some given path, if i try to access the file from lets say mobile phone, this path won't exists, and the error which I have stated in my last comment is printed..

Comment: BTW: Python3 has standard module `http` which can be used also as simple server `python3 -m http.server --cgi` and it will serve all files in folder in which you run it. And run files from subfolder `cgi-bin/` or `cgi/` - see at the end of doucumentation [http](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler)

Comment: but if you access WWW server then it is NOT run on mobile device but on server. So I don't understand how do you access it from mobile device - as web page or as normal script?

Comment: I am connecting to my localhost and just requesting the file directly (from mobile) just to test if it is working example: http://192.168.1.3/HelloWorld.py Where HelloWorld.py contains just print("Hello World") and I just want to print it. Sorry if it is dumb really I feel always stupid when starting new language/framework there is always really stupid questions at the start

Comment: if you connect from mobile device to `http://192.168.1.3/HelloWorld.py` on server (with CGI) then code should be executed on server, not on mobile device. If CGI doesn't work then server may try to send code as normal file and then mobile may try to run it locally but it is wrong - CGI server should run code on server. At start I would put code in subfolder `cgi-bin` to run it as `http://192.168.1.3/cgi-bin/HelloWorld.py` because most CGI servers as default run code only in this subfolder.

Comment: BTW: CGI has also some rules how to generate data which it will send to client. It may need at start extra information for HTTP protocol - and using only `print("Hello World")` may generate wrong data and it may have problem to send it. You should have it in any tutorial for CGI scripts. See module [cgi](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/cgi.html)

Comment: Well I really don't know why, but I have used agian shebang and now it works no matter from what device I am accessing it... And you are right about that using print("hello world") only won't work, you have to declare Content Headers and after that leave one empty print() after it, after that it is available. Thanks for all suggestions <3. I would try to use mod_python. Paste last 2 comments as answer if you want, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you connect from mobile device to `http://192.168.1.3/HelloWorld.py` on server with `CGI` then code should be executed on server, not on mobile device. If `CGI` doesn't work then server may try to send code as normal file and then mobile mdevice ay try to run it locally but it is wrong - `CGI` server should run code on server.

At start I would put code in subfolder `cgi-bin` to run it as `http://192.168.1.3/cgi-bin/HelloWorld.py` because most `CGI` servers as default run code only in this subfolder.

---

On Linux script would need shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

in first line and it should be executable

```
chmod a+x script.py
```

---

`CGI` has also some rules how to generate data which it will send to client. It may need at start extra information for `HTTP` protocol - and using only print("Hello World") may generate wrong data and it may have problem to send it. You should have it in any tutorial for `CGI` scripts. See module [cgi](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/cgi.html)

---

To run Python's code Apache needs module `mod_cgi`, `mod_fcgi` or [mod_python](http://modpython.org/)

`mod_cgi` and `mod_fcgi` can run scripts in different languages: `Python`, `Perl`, `Ruby`, etc. and even `Bash`, `PHP` or `C`/`C++`/`Java`

---

Python3 has standard module [http](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler) which can be used also as simple server

```
python3 -m http.server --cgi
```

and it will serve all files in folder in which you run it. And it runs files from subfolder `cgi-bin/` - see doc: [http](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler)